# inheriting constructors of class virtually derived.

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, virtual

I came across this question which asks its output.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class A{
      public:
            int i;
            A(int j=3):i(j){}
};
class B:virtual public A{
      public:
            B(int j=2):A(j){}
};
class C:virtual public A{
      public:
            C(int j=1):A(j){}
};
class D:public B, public C {
      public:
            D(int j=0):A(j), B(j+1), C(j+2){}
};
int main()
{
D d;
cout<<d.i;
return 0;
}
```

There are few things which I did not understand.
Please clarify these doubts.I could not google it as I did not know what to search for.

Q1. As in the code a parameterised constructor is used.Just after the colon(:) we write the constructor of the parent class.How

```
A(int j=3):i(j){}
```

is used? As i is not a class.

Q2. In the class D, the constructor for the class is using the constructors for initialising the base classes.But as it can be seen that all the constructors modify variable i of the class A only.
Then what is the sequence of the constructor calling here.

I know when we do not call the constructor of the parent class, it is explicitly called and the order is well known, but what when we implicitly call the constructor like here.

Q3. Inspite of the parameters being initialized, the value which we send in the constructor seems to make a difference.Why is it so ?

Comment: `i(j)` is a member initializer that initializes `i`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A1. `:i(j)` in `A(int j=3):i(j){}` is an initializer list. Initializer lists can specify how parent classes *and* member variables are initialized. `(j)` is the initializer for `i` and behaves similarly to initialization for a local variable: `int i(j);`. (you may be more familiar with the initialization syntax `int i = j;` which is similar. You can't use the `=` syntax in initializer lists.)

A2. Virtual base classes are always initialized exclusively by the most derived class's constructor. So `D`'s constructor initializes its `A` base class and when `D`'s constructor calls the constructors for `B` and `C` those constructors *do not* reinitialize `A`.

A3. The syntax `D(int j=0)` does not initialize the parameter. Instead it declares a *default value* for the parameter which is ignored whenever you explicitly pass a value for that parameter.

Answer (score 3):

The *ctor-initializer-list* contains the initializers for all subobjects.  That means base class subobjects and member subobjects.

Subobjects are initialized in the order in which they appear in the class definition, always.  it doesn't matter what order you put them in the *ctor-initializer-list* (although putting them in any other order is confusing when the order is ignored).

Inherited base subobject constructors are called by the constructor of the class which is directly derived... except for virtual base subobjects, which are called directly from the constructor for the most-derived object.  Virtual base subobjects are constructed before anything else.

There's no such thing as "parameters being initialized".  Those are *default arguments*, and they are ignored when an actual argument is provided.

Answer (score 0):

1) The colon `:` can be used in a constructor to call the constructors of member variables with the given arguments:

```
public:
        int i;
        A(int j=3):i(j){}
```

means that `A`'s member `i` will call its constructor with `j` as the argument.

2) Subobjects will be initialized in the order they appear in the class definition

```
class D:public B, public C
```

3) They weren't initialized, they were given default arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Q1: 
That code in the constructor between the signature of the function and before the opening bracket of the function body is called an initializer list.

The syntax of an initializer list is a listing of member variables of the class with corresponding initial values. The initial values are in parenthesis. The member variables are separate by comma's. The first variable comes after a colon.

An initializer list can also include a constructor to base class, which is what your B and C class do. Your 'A' class simply uses the form that initializes a member variable.

Q2:
To find the order that the constructors are executed in, put in some print statements. It will help you understand the order of construction. Also put in a destructor and put print statements in those too. I can't do all of your homework for you on this question. :)

Q3:
I guess by parameters being initialized you mean the default arguments? Default arguments are always always overridden if a value is actually passed into the function.

Comment: I did put print statements but the order remained same.Is it that in spite of calling the constructors implicitly, the explicit order remains same ?